# springboot ApplicationContextInitializer setActiveProfiles Why can't it take effect?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When I was using ApplicationContextInitializer, I found that I could use it to specify the activation file, but I couldn't actually get the activation file data, at first I thought it was a file format problem, but when I changed to yml configuration profile.active, I could get it, why?

```
public class MyApplicationContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer {
    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        System.out.println("setActiveProfiles");
        ConfigurableEnvironment environment = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
        environment.setActiveProfiles("dev");
    }
}
```

I used Application.yml to load the custom initlizer,this is the text.

`context: initializer: classes: com.xnew.springboot.initlister.initiallizer.MyApplicationContextInitializer`

here is the console text png.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqGf3.png)

I can see in the console that it is activated, but I can't get the parameter value of the activation configuration using @Value.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to achieve or describe. Your question is, at best, confusing/not clear.

Comment: I want to activate spring.profile.active by means of ApplicationContextInitializer

Comment: Which is the only thing I understood from your question, how you are testing this or what you are trying to do is totally unclear.

Comment: What I mean is that I want to get the value of the data in the active configuration file, such as home: addr: Zhongshan South Road in application-dev.yml, but I have not been able to read it

Comment: How are you registering this initializer? How are you loading the configuration etc. There is far too little information here to answer it.